# knockout.js not working when select list doesn't have options

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, knockout.js

I think I found a bug in knockout.js in conjuction with the asp.net mvc dropdownlist.  When supplying just a list of strings MVC doesn't render the option values on the select element.  Knockout.js won't update the value because of this.  If I use the second html snippet below by explicitly telling it properties it works.  Shouldn't knockout.js read the inner html if the options value isn't available?

**Doesn't Update**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Grade, new SelectList((IEnumerable<string>)ViewData[Config.ViewData.Grades], Model.Grade), new { data_bind = "value: selectedGrade" })
```

**Updates**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Grade, new SelectList(((IEnumerable<string>)ViewData[Config.ViewData.Grades]).Select(q => new { Text = q, Value = q }), "Value", "Text", Model.Grade), new { data_bind = "value: selectedGrade" })
```

**The first dropdown renders**

```
<select>
<option>K</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</option>
```

**The second dropdown renders**

```
<select>
<option value="K">K</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</option>
```

Comment: In your *Doesn't Update* snippet, does a drop down list even appear? I'd be surprised that it doesn't generate an error. I don't think you can just convert a list of strings to a list of select list items without helping the compiler like you did in the *Updates* snippet.

Comment: Yes it does, the options dont have values though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd call it a bug. Please open an issue on Github: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues

Comment: Looks like this is going to be fixed in 2.2, https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/commit/98ba90f264afe892499357ad256d9aaae2544aee.  Thanks Michael.